# How to reduce list only with specific sequence on elements

Tags: kotlin

I have a list: `lanesClosures: List<Boolean>` it might be [true, false, false, true, true, false]
I want to get list with following sequence: `[true, false, true, false]` and skip `[false, true]`.
How to achieve it in kotlin way?

Note: I want to achieve this in more kotlin way. And avoid using var:`

```
private fun getLaneClosureDurationSeconds(lanesClosures: List<Triple<Long, IncidentLaneId, Boolean>>): Long {
        var duration = 0L
        var closed = 0L
        var open = 0L
        for (laneClosure in lanesClosures.reversed()) {
            if (laneClosure.third) {
                closed = laneClosure.first
            } else open = laneClosure.first

            if (closed != 0L && open != 0L) {
                duration = duration + open - closed
                closed = 0L
                open = 0L
            }
        }
        return duration
    }
```

`

Comment: ok soory. I think I simplified case. `List<Triple<Long, IncidentLaneId, Boolean>>` -> this is my list. I have to filter it by rule I described upper. (by it.third  which is bool). thanks

Comment: The Input list might be also it.third -> [true, false, false, false, false, true, false]. and I need to  get only it.third from true to false pair .by indexes [0,1,5, 6]

Comment: Could it happen that the first element in (reversed) list is `false`? Are you sure your algorithm correctly handles this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to keep pairs matching some pattern, you can use `zipWithNext`(https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip-with-next.html) to obtain a new list of all the pairs in the list, then filter on your desired pattern and flatMap that again to get a list.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(
        Triple(0, 0, true), 
        Triple(1, 1, false), 
        Triple(2, 2, false), 
        Triple(3, 3, true), 
        Triple(4, 4, true), 
        Triple(5, 5, false)
    )

    val result = list.zipWithNext().filter { it.first.third && !it.second.third }.flatMap { it.toList() }

    // prints [(0, 0, true), (1, 1, false), (4, 4, true), (5, 5, false)]
    println(result)
}
```

Edited my response seeing the clarifications in your comments.

Comment: Ty for your answer. listOf(
        Triple(0, 0, true), 
        Triple(1, 1, false), Triple(6, 6, false),
        Triple(2, 2, false), 
        Triple(3, 3, true), 
        Triple(4, 4, true), 
        Triple(5, 5, false)
    ). but it is not gonna work in this case. I may have a randomly mixed bools.Thanks

Comment: @Demitriush can you order the list? If so, just call `.sortedBy { it.first }`(or whatever key you can order on) before `.zipWithNext`. If not, please specify. What does the Long in the Triple represent? Also, I would recommend you to drop the Triple class and just specify a class. That way, you get a better representation of what the data is, and what the different fields specify.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Saved my day! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stream filter with a comparison conditional that toggles between true and false every time it matches.

The state should be stored outside the stream in a closure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`chunked`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) on the input `List<Boolean>` and filter out undesired pairs, maybe like this:

```kotlin
fun main () {
    // example list
    val lanesClosures : List<Boolean> = listOf(true, false, false, true, true, false)
                                                    
    val chunkedFilteredFlattened: List<Boolean> =
            // chunk the list into pairs,
            lanesClosures.chunked(2)
                        // filter out [false, true]
                        .filter{ it != listOf(false, true) }
                        // and flatten the pairs to single values
                        .flatMap { it }
    // print the result
    println(chunkedFilteredFlattened)
}
```

output:

```
[true, false, true, false]
```

Comment: [true, false, false, true, true, false] it will doesnot work in case [true, false, false, false, true, true, false]

Comment: @Demitriush that's correct but it wasn't obvious from your question. Your example in the question could be a little clearer, I thought about comparing consecutive pairs in your list.

Comment: Yes sory. I added note i question

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to filter out sequentially repeated boolean values, making alternating series, then I would suggest approach using sequences.

If you want to take **first** of repeated values (i.e. (1, true), (2,true), (3, false) will transform to (1, true), (3, false)):

```kotlin
fun filteredLanesClosuresFirst(lanesClosures: List<Triple<Long, Any, Boolean>>) = sequence {
    var prevState: Boolean? = null
    lanesClosures.forEach {
        if (prevState != it.third) {
            prevState = it.third
            yield(it)
        }
    }
}
```

A bit more cumbersome variant (but completely without `var`):

```kotlin
fun filteredLanesClosuresFirst2(lanesClosures: List<Triple<Long, Any, Boolean>>): Sequence<Triple<Long, Any, Boolean>> {
    if (lanesClosures.isEmpty()) return emptySequence()

    val iterator = lanesClosures.iterator()
    return generateSequence(iterator.next()) { prev ->
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            val current = iterator.next()
            if (prev.third != current.third) return@generateSequence current
        }
        null
    }
}
```

If you want to take **last** of repeated values (i.e. (1, true), (2,true), (3, false) will transform to (2, true), (3, false)):

```kotlin
fun filteredLanesClosuresLast(lanesClosures: List<Triple<Long, Any, Boolean>>) = sequence {
    var prev: Triple<Long, Any, Boolean>? = null
    lanesClosures.forEach {
        if (prev != null && prev?.third != it.third) {
            yield(prev)
        }
        prev = it
    }
}
```

A bit more cumbersome variant (but completely without `var`):

```kotlin
fun filteredLanesClosuresLast2(lanesClosures: List<Triple<Long, Any, Boolean>>): Sequence<Triple<Long, Any, Boolean>> {
    if (lanesClosures.isEmpty()) return emptySequence()

    val indexOfFirstLast = lanesClosures.windowed(2).indexOfFirst { it[0].third != it[1].third }
    if (indexOfFirstLast == -1) return sequenceOf(lanesClosures.last())

    fun getNextAlternatingLastIndex(prevIndex: Int): Int {
        val prevValue = lanesClosures[prevIndex].third
        val index = lanesClosures.drop(prevIndex + 1)
            .windowed(2)
            .indexOfFirst { it[0].third != prevValue && it[0].third != it[1].third }
        return if (index == -1) -1 else prevIndex + 1 + index
    }

    return generateSequence(indexOfFirstLast, ::getNextAlternatingLastIndex).takeWhile { it != -1 }.map { lanesClosures[it] }
}
```

I believe the most *kotlin way* will be making simple generic extension functions:

```
fun <T> List<T>.makeAlternatingTakingFirstRepeating(action: (T) -> Any?) = sequence {
    var prev: Any? = Any()
    this@makeAlternatingTakingFirstRepeating.forEach {
        val current = action(it)
        if (prev != current) {
            prev = current
            yield(it)
        }
    }
}

fun <T> List<T>.makeAlternatingTakingLastRepeating(action: (T) -> Any?) = sequence {
    var prev: T? = null
    this@makeAlternatingTakingLastRepeating.forEach {
        if (prev != null && prev?.let(action) != action(it)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            yield(prev as T)
        }
        prev = it
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 val result = lanesClosures
        .makeAlternatingTakingFirstRepeating { it.third } //or last repeating
        .map { it.first }
        .windowed(size = 2, step = 2) { it[1] - it[0] }
        .sum()
```